# The connection between Kurdish music and the sound of horses galloping?

Tags: folk

The characteristic background rhythm of Kurdish music (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pl961nureJw)) is very similar to the sound of [horses galloping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2RlWuqVMZw). Given that horses were domesticated by Indo-Europeans, it seems likely there could be a direct connection between the two.

Is there any research about this?  This similarity is obvious (in my opinion) but when I search on the internet I find nothing said about this similarity.

Comment: Could you clarify on what you are asking?

Comment: @Phillip Siebold. excuse me I am not familiar with musical term . in many Kurdish music the background repeated sound (I don't know what is the term) is very similar to horse galloping (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdFXn8KfdK0)). so maybe the background reapeated sound is an adaptation from horse galloping. while this similarty is obvious (in my opinion) but when I search in internet nothing was said about this similarity.